# How do I make my Flow see the steps of the Approval Process as it jumps from step to step per criteria?

Tags: visual-workflow, administration, approval-process, developer

I hit a complete brick wall with creating a logical solution for a flow I’m working on. Maybe you guys can steer me in the right direction?

I’m creating a flow that will send email reminders for an approval process that has 21 steps. Each step has its own criteria.

My logic was to have the flow setup where it goes step by step with decisions mimicking the criteria of the steps in the approval process to determine which step it’s in, and then creating a picklist field with the names of the approval steps which would be used in the flow and in the approval steps to tell the flow which step the approval process is currently in and who to send it to.

- The major logic flaw that I realized was that say the approval process starts at step 2 matching the criteria and when step 2 is approved, depending in the record, it’ll go to either step 4 or step 5…

  - this is where I’m stuck because with my logic, the flow will see that an action has been made within the approval process, go back up and start to evaluate the elements but it’ll stop back at step two because that criteria hasn’t changed, creating a loop.
  - While the approval process will continue to go down the line, the flow won’t know which step it’s in…
- I can’t seem to figure out how to make it understand that the approval process has moved on to either step 4 OR step 5 depending on what the criteria is in the record….
- The approval process kind of goes in sections so it’ll jump around…
- I have no idea how to make the flow understand which step the approval process jumped to after approval… does that make sense? Hopefully this isn’t too confusing lol Do you have any ideas??

[image]
[image]